# What is and what do a WebLogic Server domain?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, application-server, bea

I am a Java developer and I am pretty new in web application development using Java and I have the following doubts.

We are developing web app deployed on **Oracle WebLogic Server**.

What exactly is the **weblogic domains**? From what I understand each application use a definied domain. But what it exactly does?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Oracle [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/e14140/intro.htm#WLDCW101):

> A domain is the basic administrative unit of WebLogic Server. It
>   consists of one or more WebLogic Server instances, and logically
>   related resources and services that are managed, collectively, as one
>   unit.

[image: Weblogic Domain img]

So it's an administrative container, you should think of the following: 1 domain equals 1 Administration Server.

The Administration Server:

> A domain includes one WebLogic Server instance that is configured as
>   an administration server. All changes to configuration and deployment
>   of applications are done through the administration server.
>
> The administration server provides a central point for managing the
>   domain and providing access to the WebLogic Server administration
>   tools. These tools include the following:
>
> - WebLogic Server Administration Console: Graphical user interface to the administration server.
> - WebLogic Server Node Manager: A Java program that enables you to start and stop server instances—both administration servers and
>     managed servers—remotely, and to monitor and automatically restart
>     them after an unexpected failure.
> - Note that the node manager is installed on all the machines that host any server instance – both administration server and managed
>     servers.

Comment: Is a domain mandatory ? Can you deploy an application without creating one ?

Comment: I think that is the standard way of doing it. Create a domain.

Comment: So, what are the tradeoffs between using one Admin Server (i.e. having only one domain for all your managed servers) vs using multiple Admin Servers (having multiple domains)?

Answer (score 0):

A WebLogic **Domain** is a concept that represents an environment.

- A **Domain** includes an **Administration Server**, and 1 or more **Managed Servers**
- **Managed Servers** are basically Java servers running on the physical machine or VM, which can each contain 1 or more Managed Servers.
- **Managed Servers** can be organized into **Clusters**
- A **Domain** also contains **Resources**, such as database connections pools, which can be used by **Applications**.
- **Applications** and **Resources** are deployed on to specific **Managed Servers** or **Cluster(s)** (a Resource should be deployed on the same Managed Server or Cluster as the Application that needs it)
- A **Domain** usually contains multiple applications.
- **Clusters** abstract the **Managed Servers** as a group, so it's easy to scale an **Application** deployment by adding **Managed Servers** to a **Cluster**.
- Multiple **Clusters** in the same **Domain** can help segregate **Applications** and **Resources** according to their usage requirements.
- **Dynamic Clusters** include rules for scaling the number of **Managed Servers** in and out according to specific metrics.

Furthermore:

- There is 1 Admin Server per Domain. Usually there is 1 Domain per group of machines running Managed Servers in the Domain.
- While the Admin Server manages what is deployed where, another service, the Node Manager, runs on each physical machine or VM to manage the life-cycle of the Managed Server (start, stop, health check) and reports to the Admin Server.

Answer (score -2):

This link from oracle docs has precisely defined weblogic domain.It has detailed the various ways of dividing your application may be logically,physically or based on size.Specifically below sections from the link might answer your question

What Is a Domain?

Organizing Domains

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/domain_config/understand_domains.html

I found the below link useful as well:

http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=1914